# How to initialize an Option array to None in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, constructor

I have defined a class in Scala (2.9.1) as follows:

```
class A(val neighbors: Array[Option[A]]) {
   def this() = this(new Array[Option[A]](6))

   // class code here ...
}
```

My problem is that neighbors is initialized with nulls, when I would like it to be initialized with `None`.  I tried this, but the compiler complains with the error message "not found: type None":

```
class A(val neighbors: Array[Option[A]]) {
   def this() = this(new Array[None](6))

   // class code here ...
}
```

I can do this, which gives the desired behavior, but it doesn't seem very elegant:

```
class A(val neighbors: Array[Option[A]]) {
   def this() = this(Array(None, None, None, None, None, None))

   // class code here ...
}
```

So, my question is, what is the best way to do this?

EDIT:  I am referring to the behavior when `new A()` is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be

```
Array.fill(6)(None:Option[A])
```

Additionally you can change your class's constructor to take a default parameter like this:

```
class A(val neighbors: Array[Option[A]] = Array.fill(6)(None))
```

Comment: If the `Array.fill` is in a `this()` constructor, there's no need for the type annotation on `None`, because the type of `neighbors` is already known and the array's type can be inferred.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this?

```
def this() = this(Array.fill(6) {Option.empty})
```